# Debugging month-dependent PHP scripts

Tags: php, debugging, testing, time

A bit new to php, yet I have a PHP script that basically checks what month are we in, and according to that it perofrms a certain action.

Now, is there a way to make the php environment "think" that we are in a different month, so I could test out the reaction over the 12 month without actually waiting for a year to pass, lol.

Comment: Sure, just use a variable containing the time instead of now().

Comment: [libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime) or [Flux Capacitor](https://github.com/majek/fluxcapacitor)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getMonth(){
return 3;
}

function getMonth(){
return date('n');

}
```

Use a function, use the 2nd one in your real code, and the first one when you are testing.

You could get jiggy with it and include it in a file, just comment out one or the other as needed.